# Search input on mobile device

Tags: interaction-design, mobile, user-behavior, search, mobile-web

I'm designing a mobile-web app (ie: not a native app) for touchscreen smartphones.

When you add a search input, do you need to add the search button (for processing the search) or use the one present in the keyboard?
If user perform a search, he will

1. tap on the search field
2. The keyboard appears, he taps his search terms
3. When he's finished he taps "go" on the keyboard.

Is it necessary to add a search button (if keyboard doesn't show the "go" button for example)

Do all touch devices have the "go" button?

[image: See a screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You should include a "search" or "go" button**.

Not all smartphones use a touch screen to type, even if they are touch capable.  Many have slide out keyboards for example which they use.  Most Blackberry smartphones use a keyboard for all input and then you can't rely on the go button being there.

Comment: In addition, a physical button with alternate text is an escape that facilitates accesability and as such it's always a good idea to implement. It's not mandatory, but it is smart to depend on your own interface, instead of having to depend on OS keyboards. Keep in mind people might use custom keyboards that could potentially function differently (in different languages).

Answer (score 1):

**Have to use a button**

With regards to accessibility as well, it is better to use a button with the action which describe the specific event that a user initiate always. Provide a better usability